# Binding takes time to update View - Angular 2

Tags: jquery, binding, angular

I am facing a small issue here. I am binding an object array with view with some initial values in it. Then I am pushing some more values to that array and after the values are pushed it is refreshed in the view. But the moment they are refreshed, I need to hide them using jQuery and do some other calculations as well.

My Code -

```
Items:Array<Item> = [];
```

Then I am pushing values to this array inside a function -

```
var allItems = [];
allItems = getData();
allItems.forEach((Item)=>{
    this.Items.push(Item);
});

this.Items.forEach((Item)=>{
    jQuery('#'+Item.id).hide();
    jQuery('#'+Item.id)[0].style.top = this.getTopPosition();
    jQuery('#'+Item.id)[0].style.left = this.getLeftPosition();
});
```

But unfortunately, jQuery is not able to find the Item with that Id in the DOM(View). I used debugger to find whats going wrong and found that DOM has not been updated yet with the Items.

To resolve this temporarily, I am using setTimeout() -

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.Items.forEach((Item)=>{
        jQuery('#'+Item.id).hide();
        jQuery('#'+Item.id)[0].style.top = this.getTopPosition();
        jQuery('#'+Item.id)[0].style.left = this.getLeftPosition();
    });
},1);
```

Now I need a cleaner and better way to make this functionality work. Is there any event that is fired when change occurs in the model? Or maybe I could access the change detector? subscribe to change detector?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try not to mix angular and jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do. `setTimeout()` is the best arroach using jQuery. Alternatively you could use a binding to hide items.

```
<my-item *ngFor="let item in allItems" [hidden]="isHidden(item.id)" ></my-item>
```

```
isHidden(id) {
  return id == this.someHiddenId;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention in my question but what If I need to do other things? Like I am also setting the top and left position of that Item div. But I  am not able to do that :(

Comment: You can also bind that like `<my-item [style.top.px]="itemTop">` where `itemTop` is a property on your component with a value like `150`. You should try to avoid jQuery in Angular2

Comment: I dont want to bind it. Actually I want to bind it just for the first time. But thats not possible in angular 2. If I bind it, and add some other elements near or any where in the view, all elements are re-positioned.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "only the first time"

Comment: I mean one time binding, not one-way or two way binding.

Comment: If you don't change the value of the property you bind to then the binding is not updated. I'm still not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have some Items updated automatically, and these Items have their own absolute positioned div elements with a specific top and left positions given to it. These top and left positions are stored in '%' and not in 'px'. When I am binding those values, and if any other Item is added anywhere around it (a big sized div element) then they change its positions automatically. If I DON'T bind top and left position and give the top and left positions directly using jQuery, whatever I add on the container, It won't affect top and left positions of any other divs. Basically, positions are recalculated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110964/discussion-between-gunter-zochbauer-and-rehban-khatri).

Comment: You don't need to bind to `px`. You can also bind `%` like `[style.top.%]="itemTop"` or `[style.top]="itemTop"` where `itemTop` is `15vh`

Comment: It doesn't matter If I bind to % or px, the problem is binding, position will be recalculated if the containers size is changed. I don't want this to happen

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem like this and wanted to get a notification or call a callback function after ng-repeat finishes binding all the element. That time I found a solution and wrote a generic directive to reuse it in every project. Also I wrote a small post regarding this. [Check this link](http://sktajbir.blogspot.com/2015/01/callback-function-after-angular.html). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do it right now but will update this answer when I'll write a new directive.